# Как сделать текст зеленым?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Необходимо с помощью js сделать 'Текст' зеленым

Даны стили

```
table .c {color: red}
.a .c {color: green}
```

И разметка

```
<table id="t">
    <tr>
        <td class="c">Текст</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Мой код

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        table .c {color: red;}
        .a .c {color: green;}
    </style>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('t').className = 'a'
        //t.rows[0].className = 'a'
        //t.className = 'a'
    </script>

    <table id="t">
        <tr>
            <td class="c">Текст</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Пытался сделать разными способами, текст все равно красный. Ошибка скорее всего очень банальная, но не могу понять в чем она. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: я, видимо, дальтоник https://jsfiddle.net/qd5uvab9/

Comment: Странно, у меня в трех браузерах текст красный. Спасибо за полезную ссылку.

Comment: это была шутка - у вас наверное опечатки - дважды класс "с" определен

Comment: Но вы же вставили такой же код как у меня. Вроде нет опечаток. Где класс "c" определен дважды?

Comment: вот здесь - ` table .c {color: red;}
        .a .c {color: green;}`

Comment: Так это начальное условие. Мне нужно использовать только js

Comment: найдите элемент с классом "c" и поменяйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

находит ваш блок с текстом под классу `.c` и применяет стиль к цвету шрифта `color` :
`document.querySelector(".c").style.color = 'green';`